# UpdateView and CreateView share common JavaScript function

Tags: django, django-views

**Django 1.9.7**

Updating and creation are more or less similar operations. Sometimes I would like to add JavaScript events as widget attrs. For example, users select a gender. Depending on that I'd like to show or hide maiden name. This is just an example of some operation common to UpdateView and CreateView.

I tried to organize it as a mixin, but failed: UpdateView and CreateView both use FormMixin. If I organize another mixin inheriting from FormMixin, I get a clash.

Could you help me understand how to cope without repeating the code?

```
class PersonUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Person
    fields = ['gender', 'last_name']

class PersonCreate(CreateView):
    model = Person
    fields = ['gender', 'last_name']
    redirect_name = "people"

    field_attrs = {'gender':  {'onchange':"alert('G')"},
                   'last_name': {'onclick': "alert('LN')"},
                   }     

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super(PersonCreate, self).get_form(form_class)
        for key, value in self.field_attrs.items():
            form.fields[key].widget.attrs = value;
        return form
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mixin should be a simple class:

```
class CreateUpdateMixin(object):

    model = Person
    fields = ['gender', 'last_name']

    field_attrs = {'gender':  {'onchange':"alert('G')"},
                   'last_name': {'onclick': "alert('LN')"},
                   }
```

Then you use it like so:

```
class PersonUpdateView(CreateUpdateMixin, UpdateView):
    pass

class PersonCreate(CreateUpdateMixin, CreateView):
    redirect_name = "people"   

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super(PersonCreate, self).get_form(form_class)
        for key, value in self.field_attrs.items():
            form.fields[key].widget.attrs = value;
        return form
```

Comment: solarissmoke, thank you for the answer. But I can't understand the idea. You offer to redefine get_form method in PersonCreate and in PersonUpdateView? Then a mixin doesn't know about those views. But the views do know about the mixin. Special code is in views: fields and their attributes. General code should be in a mixin. Anyway, it seems that you offer duplicating of code if I understand you correctly. And this is more complicated than just redefine get_form methods without any mixins. Pardon, if I haven't caught the idea.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I didn't understand your question. I don't really understand your comment either unfortunately...

Comment: solarissmoke, please, excuse me if I was clumsy in explanations. I have coped with the problem using mixin. Not like you suggested, but it works perfectly. Thank you for your support.